# Using NaCl to benchmark new crypto algorithm

Tags: algorithm, nacl-cryptography

For my master thesis, I have to implement some new Cryptographic functions so that I can have a brief overview of their performance. I have checked on the internet and it seems that the NaCl library was created for this purpose.

To be more precise with you, I don't really need to get hardware-independant measures, I only need to have some idea of the performance of the different versions of the implementation. I have downloaded the archive as described on http://nacl.cr.yp.to/ but I'm a bit lost at this point. Effectively, I don't really need the implementation of the existing algorithms (maybe I only need to keep AES such that I can have a comparaison point) but I need to add the new ones I have implemented. These implementations are C code.

On the website, it is explained how you can collaborate by writing new implementation but I'm not pretty sure I have understood how to do to add a new algorithm.

Can someone help me by giving me a link to a tutorial or by telling me what I need to modify to only measure my implementations ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Benchmarking against some existing algorithms such as AES really provides no meaningful information since many or most common CPU hardware provided some form of acceleration for AES, this includes Intel CPU chips as well as some ARM CPUs. As an example; an iPhone 6S has a hardware crypto engine that is 500-1000 times faster than a software AES implementation.

Comment: Yes, I know but you can disable this functionnality in the bios. My goal is to have a point of comparison that's all :)

Comment: Didn't you confuse SUPERCOP with NaCl?